# .htaccess Rewrite all images or css from source

Tags: html, css, image, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Right now my project is direct uploaded on the domain.
[image]
And i use this rewrite rules,

```
RewiteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +MultiViews
RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/(.+?\.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|css|js))$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^product/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/$ /shop/product-page.php?pr=$1&id=$2&cat=$3 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^shop/(.*)/(.*)/$ /shop.php?cat=$1&catn=$2 [QSA,L]
```

The problem is CSS and images, won't work... can i fix this ?
for example for picture link in the page is uploads/images (from some images)
i can get url like get uploads/images/image.png and after with rerwire rule add a / to path ? > /uploads/images/image.png

Thanks !

Comment: You can add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: I think is working, do ou have any ideea, my slider is not workig but i see here all the scripts are loaded.